# Collapse and Expand not working in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have a side bar menu there are items  home, gallery , who is the best and competition.

There is a collapse and expand drop down for gallery and who is the best and that are working properly.There in the competition tab a dropdown name toplist this week, and the toplist this week have another drop down of 5 items.I want that like gallery when i clik the competition the toplist this week appear and when i click the toplist this week the items appear and like gallery there be expand and collapse.

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.php"><img src="images/home.png"/> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1"><img src="images/categories.png"/>Gallery</a><img src="images/up.gif" alt=""/>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="cars.php"><img src="images/cars.png"/>Cars</a></li>
        <li><a href="movies.php"><img src="images/movies.png"/>Movies</a></li>
        <li><a href="babies.php"><img src="images/baby.jpg"/>Babies</a></li>
        <li><a href="puppies.php"><img src="images/puppies.png"/>Puppies</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1"><img src="images/best.png"/>Who is the best</a><img src="images/up.gif" alt=""/>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/voteforcars.png"/>Vote for Cars</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/voteforsport.png"/>Vote for Sports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/voteformovies.jpg"/>Vote for Movies</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1"><img src="images/toplits.png"/>Competition</a><img src="images/up.gif" alt=""/>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1"><img src="images/top.jpg"/>Toplists of Weak</a><img src="images/up.gif" alt=""/>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/sports.png"/>Sports</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/cars.png"/>Cars</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/movies.png"/>Movies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/images.png"/>Images</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/baby.jpg"/>Babies</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}

#nav, #nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 199px;
}

#nav ul {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

#nav li {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

#nav ul li {
    margin-top: -23px;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
}

#nav li a {
    background-color: #d4d5d8;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 28px;
    outline: 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li a.sub {
    background: #d4d5d8 url("../images/down.gif") no-repeat;
}

#nav li a + img {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    height: 28px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
}

#nav li a img {
    border-width: 0px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 24px;
}

#nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #bcbdc1;
}

#nav ul li a {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 22px;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #444;
}

#nav ul li a img {
    background: url("images/bulb.png") no-repeat;
    border-width: 0px;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 16px;
}

#nav ul li:nth-child(odd) a img {
    background: url("images/bulb2.png") no-repeat;
}

#nav a.sub:focus {
    background: #bcbdc1;
    outline: 0;
}

#nav a:focus ~ ul li {
    margin-top: 0;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s linear;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s linear;
    -o-transition: 0.4s linears;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s linears;
    transition: 0.4s linear;
}

#nav a:focus + img, #nav a:active + img {
    display: block;
}

#nav a.sub:active {
    background: #bcbdc1;
    outline: 0;
}

#nav a:active ~ ul li {
    margin-top: 0;
}

#nav ul:hover li {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/502n03eL/

Comment: Where is your CSS code!

Comment: Please consider beautifying your HTML and CSS before posting — it is extremely hard to read when it's not done. Also, your HTML is invalid because the last `<li>` and `<ul>` are not closed.

Comment: That's way too much code to look at. Prepare a small subset of your code which reproduces the problem. That's the way you should go about debugging anyway.

Comment: it works for me (but it's an extremely **ugly** design)

Comment: have you notice the competition menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this css this might be work

```
#nav {

     border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
}
#nav, #nav ul, #nav ul ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    width:199px;
}
#nav ul, #nav ul ul {
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
#nav li {
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}
#nav ul li, #nav ul ul li {
    margin-top:-23px;

    -moz-transition:  0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
}
#nav li a {
    background-color:#d4d5d8;
    color:#000;
    display:block;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:28px;
    outline:0;
    padding-left:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li a.sub {
    background:#d4d5d8 url("../images/down.gif") no-repeat;
}

#nav li a + img {
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    height:28px;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:200px;
}
#nav li a img {
    border-width:0px;
    height:24px;
    line-height:28px;
    margin-right:8px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:24px;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#bcbdc1;
}
#nav ul li a, #nav ul ul li a {
    background-color:#eee;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    color:#000;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:22px;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#ddd;
    color:#444;
}
#nav ul li a img, #nav ul li ul a img {
    background: url("images/bulb.png") no-repeat;
    border-width:0px;
    height:16px;
    line-height:22px;
    margin-right:5px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:16px;
}
#nav ul li:nth-child(odd) a img, #nav ul ul li:nth-child(odd) a img {
    background:url("images/bulb2.png") no-repeat;
}
#nav a.sub:focus {
    background:#bcbdc1;
    outline:0;
}
#nav a:focus ~ ul li ul li{
margin-top:-23px;
}
#nav a:focus ~ ul li {
    margin-top:0;

    -moz-transition:  0.4s linear;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s linear;
    -o-transition: 0.4s linears;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s linears;
    transition: 0.4s linear;
}
#nav ul a:focus ~ ul li {
    margin-top:0;

    -moz-transition:  0.4s linear;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s linear;
    -o-transition: 0.4s linears;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s linears;
    transition: 0.4s linear;
}
#nav a:focus + img, #nav a:active + img {
    display:block;
}
#nav a.sub:active {
    background:#bcbdc1;
    outline:0;
}
#nav a:active ~ ul li, #nav ul a:active ~ ul li {
    margin-top:0;
}

#nav ul:hover li {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

You can see fiddle here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/502n03eL/3/)

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. Sir when we click on the toplist this week then the drop down shows but the top list this menu become hide. Can we see both in same time

Comment: I will try my best but now m bit busy will edit answer if done but may be after 22hrs as I am travelling

Comment: do you want to use javascript

Comment: Hi, I have created new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/vo9p36bf/. I have used jquery. and its working fine.

Comment: sir i tried it but not working...i don't know what the problem is.